# Extract nth line of a paragraph using <br>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that will take a paragraph in HTML that looks like this;

```
<p>
One<br>
Two<br>
Three<br>
Four<br>
</p>
```

...and will use the `<br>` to select a specified line that can then be used. Something similar to this snippet below would be helpful for implementation, where `1` is the line number;

```
function addText() {
    var input = document.getElementById('TARGET');
    input.value = input.value +getLine("SOURCE", 1);
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What would be the expected output of this function? What have you tried?

Comment: Will you manually be putting break tags to separate lines of a paragraph? Break tags are not designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the break tags if you want to get the text by line. You just need line breaks in the text itself. You can use a function like this:

```
function getTextByLine(target, line) {
  var text = document.querySelector(target).innerHTML
  return text.trim().split('\n')[line - 1]
}
```

Test it on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fgs4bba8/4/).

---

### Update

If you want to use the break tags you can do that as well.

```
function getTextByLine(target, line) {
  var text = document.querySelector(target).innerHTML
  var lines = text.trim().split('<br>').filter(function(str) {
    return str !== '<br>'
  })
  return lines[line - 1]
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fgs4bba8/9/).

Comment: *"You don't need the break tags"* - Except that they're required for display purposes.

Comment: Sure. If that's how you're splitting up your content. Hence both options in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this

```
var para = document.getElementsbyTagName('p')[0];

var lines = para.split('\n')
```

if you want specific text except you can further go upto index.

```
lines[4].split('<br>')[0];
```

Having said that the way you are trying to achieve is not good you should class span or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing this in the DOM. If you have simple text nodes split by BR elements, then you can find the nth BR and append the text to it's previous sibling, which will be the preceding text node.

You might want to add more logic to check that it's a text node, and so on, but the following shows the basic principle:

```js
/* Modify the text at line index of P with lines separated
** by BR elements.
** Line numbers start from 1.
** @param {number} index - line number to modify
** @param {string} text - text to append to line
*/
function insertText(index, text) {

  // Get the lines
  var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  var brs = p.getElementsByTagName('br');
  var node;
  
  // Check index is in range
  if (index < 1 || index > brs.length - 1) {
    alert('Line number must be integer from 1 to ' + (brs.length - 1));
    return;
  }

  // Append the text
  node = brs[index - 1].previousSibling;
  node.nodeValue += text; 
}
```

```html
<p>
One<br>
Two<br>
Three<br>
Four<br>
</p>

<form onsubmit="insertText(this.lineNo.value, this.theText.value); return false;">
<br>Add this text:<input id="theText"> to line <input id="lineNo">.
<br><button onclick="">Insert text</button>
</form>
```